# Calculating the Jain Fairness Index of two connections - what values to use?

Tags: tcp, throughput, iperf

I'm using GNS3 and I have 3 VMs.

I established two simultaneous TCP connections to an iperf server I created on VM2.

VM-1 -- VM-2

VM-3 -- VM-2

Using the

```
iperf -c <IP of VM2>
```

command, I recieved different bandwidth values, on either the client and server.

Below I attached screenshots from the iperf results of each VM:

**VM1 client:**

[image: VM1 Client]

**VM3 client:**

[image: VM3 client]

**VM2 server:**

[image: VM2 server]

Now am I right to assume '**559 Kbits/sec**' resp. '**553 Kbits/sec**' are the throughputs?

And if I put these values in Jain's fairness formula I get a fairness of 0.9999... Is this even possible?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(((553)%2B(559))%5E2)+%2F+(2*((553%5E2)%2B(559%5E2)))

Thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a set of equal values will give a Jain of 1.  Your values are extremely similar, I calculated 0.999971.

Comment: Thank you. So you agree 553 and 559 are the right values to consider for the Jain calculation? Because that's mainly the thing I was unsure about. I was thinking maybe you need to use the 1.35 Mbit/s and 1.37 Mbit/s too.

Comment: I've limited experience with iperf, but have always seen very similar numbers on the client and server displays; yours are factor of 2 different.  I suspect VM artifact.  jain(1.35,1.37) is still 1.

Comment: ... or perhaps the exact amount of overlap of your multiple clients.